# Trying to Achieve Exposed Drop-Down Menu in Android

Tags: android, binding, dropdown, android-bottomsheetdialog

I am Trying to Achieve the Exposed Drop-Down Menu in Android I have tried this one but can't identify where I went wrong.

**DropDown_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewFeelings"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

**BottomSheetDialogConnectWifiFragment.kt**

```
class BottomSheetDialogConnectWifiFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

    private lateinit var _binding: FragmentBottomSheetDialogConnectWifiBinding
    private val items = listOf("Material", "Design", "Components", "Android")
    private lateinit var ActivityContext: Context
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        ActivityContext = context
        super.onAttach(context)
    }


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentBottomSheetDialogConnectWifiBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return _binding.root
        //
//        val arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(_binding.root.context, R.layout.dropdown_item, items)
//        _binding.autoCompleteTextFieldSsidType.setAdapter(arrayAdapter)
        _binding.autoCompleteTextFieldSsidType.apply {
            setAdapter(
                ArrayAdapter(
                    ActivityContext,
                    R.layout.dropdown_item,
                    items
                )
            )
        }

    }

    companion object {
        const val TAG = "CustomBottomSheetDialogFragment"
    }

}
```

**fragment_bottom_sheet_dialog_connect_wifi**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    tools:context=".Fragments.BottomSheetDialogConnectWifiFragment">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:elevation="10dp"
                android:foregroundGravity="center_vertical"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/black"
                app:cardCornerRadius="100dp">

                <!--YOUR CONTENT-->
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                android:id="@+id/idTVCourseTracks"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Add Network"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/tilSsid"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/idTVCourseTracks"
                android:keyboardNavigationCluster="true">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Enter The SSID" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/textFieldSsidType"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tilSsid"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp">

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextFieldSsidType"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:hint="Enter The SSID"
                    android:inputType="none" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/textFieldPassword"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textFieldSsidType"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Password" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/idBtnDismiss"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textFieldPassword"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:text="Connect"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:theme="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.Material3.Button" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

I Created An bottomSheet in Android/kotlin and trying to solve this cant understood where i missing some thing to
i have try with .Apply{}Method And also with the normally but both of them not worked for me

Comment: Try unwrap linear layout from dropdown item xml, and use MaterialTextView directly.

Comment: Still not working

Comment: Then few more things you could try. 1. try with ```android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item``` instead of ```R.layout.dropdown_item```. 2. Try MaterialAutoCompleteTextView instead of AutoCompleteTextView

Comment: i tried in activity and it's working well, seems like issue is due to BottomSheetDialogFragment() expanding bottomsheet

Comment: Are you applying adapter to the view after return statement (in onCreateView)?

Comment: same code in Activity Working but in BottomSheet Fragment

Comment: No. I mean, when I see the code you posted, you are doing ```_binding.autoCompleteTextFieldSsidType.apply...``` after return statement which is obiviously will not run. Move those lines above return.

Comment: Also if possible, move those lines into onViewCreated method to make sure views are rendered before accessing them.

Comment: Like this?
 
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        _binding.autoCompleteTextFieldSsidType.apply {
            setAdapter(
                ArrayAdapter(
                    ActivityContext,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                    items
                )
            )
        }
    }

Comment: yes thats right